# Windows Script to create folder in explorer using user prompted input

Tags: windows, batch-file, hierarchy, directory

Thanks in advance for any help...I've done some coding in the past in C, matlab, Java, VHDL, Verilog, however I'm unfamiliar with batch files and how they are structured.

I'm trying to write a batch file in windows using notepad to create a new job folder in windows explorer with a name given by user prompted input and then create a new hierarchy of folders in this new folder. As of now I can right click anywhere in windows explorer and execute my script to create a hierarchy of folders however I've be unsuccessful in trying to get user input. I can get the command prompt to come up and ask the user to "Enter Job Name:" but cannot seem to discover the correct way to use this input to create the folder. I would prefer it to be a windows pane but command line is fine if it's too involved to use a windows pane. Lastly I would like to be able to give the user a choice of what type of job they wish to create and then create a different hierarchy of folders based on their selection however I haven't gotten this far yet. Here is what I have so far, I have commented out some things I've tried:

```
#strfolder = InputBox("Please enter a name for your new folder:")
#set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
#objFSO.CreateFolder "Z:\" & strfolder


#set mydir = %cd%
#cd %mydir%
set /p jobName = Enter Job Name: 

ECHO %jobName% /b 
md %jobName%
#cd /d \%jobName%
cd %cd%\%jobName%

#set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
#objFSO.CreateFolder "C:\Users\jarcher\Downloads\ins\test" & strfolder


md 1.Development
md 1.Development\1.Budgets
md 1.Development\2.Manufacturers

md "2.Plans and Specs"
md "2.Plans and Specs"\1.Plans
md "2.Plans and Specs"\2.Specs

md 3.Pricing
md 3.Pricing\1.Quotes
md 3.Pricing\2.Worksheets

md 4.Sumbittals
md 4.Sumbittals\"1.Submittal Reviews"

md 5.Orders
md 5.Orders\"1.Order Summaries"
md 5.Orders\"2.Confirmation Pages"

md 6.Closeout
md 6.Closeout\"1.O&M Manuals"
md 6.Closeout\2.Warranty
```

Comment: To comment-out code lines in batch files prefix them with `rem `...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the `=`:

```
set /p jobName=Enter Job Name:
```

Otherwise a space is part of the name of the variable!

Comment: (same with `set mydir = %cd%` and `set objFSO = ...`)

Comment: Great thanks for the answer! Didn't think a space could cause the problem. Any insight on the windows GUI portion of it?

Comment: You're welcome! For user prompts there is only `set /P` (built-in) and `choice` in batch scripting. The latter could be used to provide a selection list in command prompt. Type `choice /?` for help (and to find out whether it is available on your system).